# global variable doesn't reset after validating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a multi step form and on one of the pages i have a list of roles in form of checkoxes. the behaviour i have right now is that the first time i create a user it works smoothly without problem but the second time is that when I finish this creation the global variable that I used for the activation and disabling of the next button doesn't reset

here is the code

```
var rolesCheck = [] ;
export default function RolesForm(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { setDisabled } = props;

  if(rolesCheck.length === 0){
    setDisabled(true)
  }
  function filling(rolesCheck,element) {
    if (rolesCheck.indexOf(element) !== -1) {
      rolesCheck.splice(rolesCheck.indexOf(element),1);
      if (rolesCheck.length === 0) {
        setDisabled(true);
      }
    } else {
      rolesCheck.push(element);
      setDisabled(false);
    }
  }

  function getRoles(x) {
    return x.map((role, key) => {
      if (role.name) {
        return (
          <span className={classes.span} key={key}>
            <Checkbox
              color="primary"
              name={role.value}
              value={role.value}
              onChange={event => {
                filling(rolesCheck,role.value);
                props.handleRoles(event);
              }}
              checked={props.selectedRoles.includes(role.value)}
            />
            {role.name}
          </span>
        );
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <Grid className={classes.root}>
      <Grid className={classes.paper}>
        <Grid>
          <Typography variant="h3">Admin :</Typography>
          <div> {getRoles(roles.admin)}</div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
          <Typography variant="h3">
            <Translate i18nKey="back_office_roles" />
          </Typography>
          <div>{getRoles(roles.back_office)}</div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

setDisabled is the function i use to activated or disable the button
setDisabled(true) disable and setDisable(false) activate

Comment: Why not declare `rolesCheck` inside of the function component so that each time it's rendered, the value is reset

Comment: Also when you say create a user, what are you doing in terms of the code you provided?

Comment: the problem is that inside the component the table never gets filled  i don't know why

Comment: there is a list of roles displayed with checkboxes and you need at least one check to continue otherwise button is disabled

Comment: Got it. I'm pretty sure your issue is with where the `rolesCheck` variable is declared, because as it is a module-level variable, once you've appended elements to it, the next time that you use this form, it will maintain those same elements

Comment: I think you would be better off converting this function component to a class and having `rolesCheck` be a `state` variable